# Is there any way to set options without any prefix in Argparser?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I'm using Argparser to handle arguments for my CLI prog. But as the time passed I think that It's not a good Idea to use it. Here comes the problem. I want to use options without any prefix character. Like **git commit** or **svn move**. I've searched a little and found that Argparse has a add_subparser() method. Let us populate our *foo* prog:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='foo', usage='%(prog)s [options]')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('add', help='a help')
parser_a.add_argument('-ap', '--add-project',
                    nargs='*',
                    action='store',
                    help="Add project")

parser_d = subparsers.add_parser('del', help='a help')
parser_d.add_argument('-dp', '--delete-project',
                    nargs='*',
                    action='store',
                    help="Delete project")

args = parser.parser_args()
```

Now let execute foo with options and print `args` namespace(I didn't the past the whole code, you get the point):

```
$ ./foo del
Namespace(delete_project=None)
$ ./foo add
Namespace(add_project=None)
```

As you see, if I execute the option `del`, **add_project** is not passed to the variable `args`. That causes problems if I have an "if clause" in my main() function like

```
def main(args):

   if args.delete_project:
      ...
   if args.add_project:
      ...
```

I'll get an **AttributeError** exception, that the Namespace has no attribute with the name **add_project** if I execute `./foo del`. Besides that, I'm not able to pass any argument to the options `del` and `add`. I've also set prefix_chars to an empty string, that didn't work either.

What is way to handle it ? Is argparse capable to create options like git,svn, etc.. or should I create my own function and handle all arguments myself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your if statements, [the argparse docs recommend something like this](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse#sub-commands):

```
parser_X.set_defaults(action=action_func)
args.action(args)
```

Then the add_action will look at add_project, and del_action at del_project.

Comment: It absolutely does. The OP is getting attribute errors on subparsers that the user didn't invoke, and I explained him how to look at the subparser that was actually used.

Comment: Bah, my mistake, I totally missed the `subparser`.

Comment: @Nick Heh. That was a bit terse, I'm leaving the explanation.

Comment: That solves exactly my problem. I have to set for every single "-bar" option the default. But It's weird that I can't  handle the arguments to the new positional `add` and `del` options. I'll better ask a new question for that. Thanks @Tobu !

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Apparently the default for `default` is `None`, which means we don't have one, so you'll have to use `True` and `False` (which is the right way anyhow).

You need to add the `default` when you add your argument to the parser:

```
parser_a.add_argument('-ap', '--add-project',
                    nargs = '*',
                    action = 'store_true',
                    default = False,
                    help = "Add project")
```

You can see the documentation for the `add_argument` method [here](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse#the-add-argument-method).  (I realize the `argparse` doc layout isn't the most conducive to figuring out how to do things that aren't called out in the examples)

Also, as Tobu appropriately points out in his answer, the unused subparsers don't get invoked, so you can't safely probe their values without at least protecting your code in a `try:` block.  However, really you should use the functionality of associating an `action` with your subparsers unless you have a much more complex situation where they need to share state.

Comment: *The default keyword argument of add_argument(), whose value defaults to None ... It doesn't solve that problem. It still does not pass add_project if I execute `foo del`

Comment: @Farslan: Bah, so really you are forced to use `True` and `False` then (and thus really `store_true` and `store_false` in your action)